# Unit System documentation

Tags: units

Is there any documentation on what consists of the unit system `"SIBase"`,`"Imperial"`, `"SI"` and `"Metric"` in the `UnitConvert` function, and the rule of what unit is returned in the results? Cause I have notices in doing `UnitConvert[Quantity[x, LengthUnit], "Metric"]` sometimes returns quantity with units in m, and other times in mm.

Answer (score 2):

i dont know about documentation, but "Metric" and "SI" appear to be the same and give a unit based on the magnitude, while "SIBase" consistently gives meters.

```
  UnitConvert[Quantity[#, "feet"], "Metric"] & /@ {.00001, 0.001, 
       0.01, .1, 1., 10., 10000.}
```

> {Quantity[3.048, "Micrometers"], Quantity[304.8, "Micrometers"], 
>    Quantity[3.048, "Millimeters"], Quantity[3.048, "Centimeters"], 
>    Quantity[30.48, "Centimeters"], Quantity[3.048, "Meters"], 
>    Quantity[3.048, "Kilometers"]}

```
  UnitConvert[Quantity[#, "feet"], "SI"] & /@ {.00001, 0.001, 0.01, .1, 
      1., 10., 10000.}
```

> {Quantity[3.048, "Micrometers"], Quantity[304.8, "Micrometers"], 
>    Quantity[3.048, "Millimeters"], Quantity[3.048, "Centimeters"], 
>    Quantity[30.48, "Centimeters"], Quantity[3.048, "Meters"], 
>    Quantity[3.048, "Kilometers"]}

```
  UnitConvert[Quantity[#, "feet"], "SIBase"] & /@ {.00001, 0.001, 
       0.01, .1, 1., 10., 10000.}
```

> {Quantity[3.048*10^-6, "Meters"], Quantity[0.0003048, "Meters"], 
>    Quantity[0.003048, "Meters"], Quantity[0.03048, "Meters"], 
>    Quantity[0.3048, "Meters"], Quantity[3.048, "Meters"], 
>    Quantity[3048., "Meters"]}

The base unit itself plays into the heuristic as well, example:

```
UnitConvert[Quantity[.158125 10.^-4, "light year"], "Metric"] -> 1. au
UnitConvert[Quantity[93. 10^6, "Miles"], "Metric"] -> 1.49669 10^8 km
```

Comment: I like your answer, maybe Helpful: [Doku](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/UnitsOverview.html) and[NIST](http://www.nist.gov/pml/pubs/sp811/index.cfm).